# Python & Pandas: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Tags: python, pandas, csv

With Python and Pandas, I'm seeking to write a script that takes the data from the `text` column,  evaluates that text with the textstat module, and then write the results back into the csv under the `word_count`column.

Here is the structure of the csv:

```
 user_id         text text_number  word_count
0       10  test text A      text_0         NaN
1       11          NaN         NaN         NaN
2       12          NaN         NaN         NaN
3       13          NaN         NaN         NaN
4       14          NaN         NaN         NaN
5       15  test text B      text_1         NaN
```

Here is my code attempt to loop the `text` column into textstat:

```
df = pd.read_csv("texts.csv").fillna('')
text_data = df["text"]
length1 = len(text_data)

for x in range(length1):
    (text_data[x])

    #this is the textstat word count operation
    word_count = textstat.lexicon_count(text_data, removepunct=True)
    output_df = pd.DataFrame({"word_count":[word_count]})
    output_df.to_csv('texts.csv', mode="a", header=False, index=False)
```

However, I recieve this error:

`TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed`

Any suggestions on how to proceed? All assistance appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible you meant to pass the string `text_data[x]` and not the Series? `word_count = textstat.lexicon_count(text_data[x], removepunct=True)`

Comment: How are you expecting to handle the NaN values?

Comment: Many thanks - it doesn't look like it. Running that code generated this error: ~TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object~

Comment: Right. Because you have NaN in the column which are `float64`. So how do you expect to handle those?

Comment: Great catch - I edited the code above to include `fillna('')`. Running the code again with the `test_data[x]` was successful, although it put it in the `user_id` column instead of `word_count`.  I should change the `header` value to `True`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The more `pandas` approach would be to use [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) + [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html). Then write the `Series` directly out [`to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_csv.html):

```
(
    df["text"].fillna('')  # Replace NaN with empty String
        .apply(textstat.lexicon_count,
               removepunct=True)  # Call lexicon_count on each value
        .rename('word_count')  # Rename Series
        .to_csv('texts.csv', mode="a", index=False)  # Write to csv
)
```

texts.csv:

```
word_count
1
0
0
0
0
1
```

---

To add a column to the existing DataFrame/csv instead of appending to the end of it can also do:

```
df['word_count'] = (
    df["text"].fillna('')  # Replace NaN with empty String
        .apply(textstat.lexicon_count,
               removepunct=True)  # Call lexicon_count on each value
)

df.to_csv('texts.csv', index=False)  # Write to csv
```

texts.csv:

```
user_id,text,text_number,word_count
text,A,text_0,1
,,,0
,,,0
,,,0
,,,0
text,B,text_1,1
```

---

To fix the current implementation, also use [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) and conditionally write the header only on the first iteration:

```
text_data = df["text"].fillna('')

for i, x in enumerate(text_data):
    # this is the textstat word count operation
    word_count = textstat.lexicon_count(x, removepunct=True)
    output_df = pd.DataFrame({"word_count": [word_count]})
    output_df.to_csv('texts.csv', mode="a", header=(i == 0), index=False)
```

texts.csv:

```
word_count
1
0
0
0
0
1
```

---

DataFrame and imports:

```
import pandas as pd
import textstat
from numpy import nan

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'user_id': ['text', nan, nan, nan, nan, 'text'],
    'text': ['A', nan, nan, nan, nan, 'B'],
    'text_number': ['text_0', nan, nan, nan, nan, 'text_1'],
    'word_count': [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]
})
```

Comment: Many thanks for the helpful breakdown. How could the data be appended to the `word_count` column?

Comment: Take a look at the second code block under "To add a column to the existing DataFrame/csv instead of appending to the end of it"

Comment: Success! Many thanks for the patient walkthrough, it's very helpful.